How can one azure application mean for Teams tab be used by multiple domains
We are working on a custom teams Tab application.
Is there a way to have multiple TEAMS_DOMAIN for a same application ?
The goal is to be able to use the same Azure application for development.
One Azure application could be linked to multiple domain, one for dev, one for staging and one for integration.
For now we need to duplicate (well manually as there is no way to copy an app parameters) the app on azure for each environment, it takes time, is not easily editable and can lead to multiple human errors
Thanks

Currently, there isn't a direct way to have multiple TEAMS_DOMAIN values for a single Azure application. Each Azure application is typically associated with a single domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#webapplicationinfo
